# Exact sizing in Maya

Tags: maya

I'm coming from modo and want to try to create mesh assets for Unity3D in Maya. As a simple example how do I create an exact 1m cube in Maya? In modo it's easy to do.

In maya I draw a roughly 1m cube onto the grid and then want to set it's exact size but the channel box already displays scale 1x1x1 even if it's not an exact 1m for each size.

How do I set it to exactly 1m (or whatever exact measurement)? Surely it must be possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your scale to meters in preferences/settings.

From the Create menu select the little square next to polygon/cube which will bring up the options, change your size in the Single-click settings to 1x1x1 then single click on the grid to place a 1x1x1 cube.